# How to map from InstanceClass enum to actual AWS instance types

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a DocumentDB instance using AWS CDK `docdb` package (Java) and I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid DB Instance class: db.d2.large (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request
ID: 41494b4b-d14f-46ff-b077-9ee73aad515f; Proxy: null)
```

I know that, for example, an `r5.large` would work, but I cannot find a way to map from the `InstanceType` enum values (`STANDARDx`, `STORAGE2`, etc.) to the actual AWS Instance type; it does not appear to be documented anywhere, and the example (in TypeScript) use happily something like `instanceType: 'r5.large'` and move on.

This is my code, for completeness:

```
    DatabaseCluster dbCluster = DatabaseCluster.Builder.create(scope, "ApiDocDb")
        .dbClusterName(dataProps.getTableName())
        .masterUser(Login.builder()
            .username(masterUsername)
            .password(SecretValue.plainText(masterPwd))
            .build())
        .instanceType(InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.STORAGE2, InstanceSize.LARGE))
        .vpc(Vpc.Builder.create(scope, "DocDB-VPC")
            .cidr("10.2.0.0/16")
            .build())
        .vpcSubnets(SubnetSelection.builder().subnetType(SubnetType.PUBLIC).build())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial and error (largely) I finally arrived at this:

```
        .instanceType(InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.MEMORY5, InstanceSize.LARGE))
```

which seems to work.
Some help from [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/instance-types/) - cross-correlating with the fact that, in the console, if one tries to add an instance, only `r5` are allowed in the drop-down.

I just wish AWS had documented that enum a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else tackling the same problem, I created a gist [1](https://gist.github.com/zanozbot/d4dc737dea855519c0805e8bfa9dc13b) of all currently available enum keys (as of CDK v2.12.0) mapped to their corresponding instance types.

Keep in mind that each instance type has a set of corresponding instance sizes [2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

---

Comment: Respect, Zan! Thanks for doing this.